# Mac OS. Apache Tomcat 8. Console window + catalina output + shutdown ctrl+c

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

I run tomcat like:

```
exec "/Users/user/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/bin/catalina.sh" start -config /Users/user/tomcat-web-config
```

but it runs in backgroud.
How to run in new console window and out catalina.out and shutdown by ctrl+c ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run tomcat in console you have to you have to use `run` command not `start`.

Do `exec "/Users/user/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/bin/catalina.sh" run -config /Users/user/tomcat-web-config` so the tomcat will run in the console so you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop the process.

OTOH

If you use the `start` command to start tomcat use `stop` to stop the server.

Comment: what about catalina out?

Comment: If you use `run` it will print in the console. If you use `start` it wont bur you can simulate it bu `tail -f /Users/user/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/logs/catalina.out`